# A sequence that does not converge weakly in $C^0[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I have to prove that the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$ does not weakly converge in $(C^0([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$.

Some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails to converge pointwise to a continuous function. Point-evaluations are bounded linear functionals on your space.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. For every $x \in (0,1)$ we have $x^n \to 0$, isn't it pointwise convergence?

Comment: @Bobech, you wanted a hint not a full solution. If it converged weakly, it would have converged pointwise (to a continuous function) too, but it actually does not. The pointwise limit of your sequence is discontinuous.

Comment: ok, now it's clear. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** consider the functional
$$f \mapsto f(t)$$
for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Let's call this functional $\phi_t$. So we get $|\langle \phi_t, f_n\rangle |=|\phi_t (f_n)|=|t^n|$ and it does not converge for $n \to \infty $ only for $t=1$. Is it suffice?

Comment: No, it converges for all $t$, but the limit does not depend continuously on $t$.

Comment: Sorry, it was 'not converge to 0'